# Place git repository on external hard drive

Tags: xcode, git, version-control, xcode6

I am using XCODE, and have recently decided to try using git (I am a lone app developer, so never really needed to use it). Because it used to take up a lot of storage space when I tried it previously, all of my current projects with git are stored on an external hard drive. I was wondering, however, whether it is possible to keep a development branch of a project on the hard drive of the mac, while keeping the main branch on the external hard drive. That way, I can merge the stable branches every few days to the external hard drive, and keep the development copy on my macbook to remove the need to carry my external hard drive with me everywhere I go. Is this possible? Any suggestions for a newbie on git?

Comment: A lot of storage space? Like... how much?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the complete history of your project really is taking so much space (but reconsider and check twice if it really does), here could be a way to make this work:

First have your complete history in your `remote` repo (external hard drive) in a branch `main` (I would keep the default branch name `master`, if I were you). Making it a bare repo is a good idea, to ease pushing later on. If you haven't done it already:

```
$ cd /mnt/your/external/drive
$ git clone --bare /repo/where/you/currently/have/the/whole/history
```

Then when you want to start a new development phase, take a shallow clone from `remote` to `local` (your laptop's hard drive)

```
$ cd $HOME/
$ git clone --depth 10 /mnt/you/external/drive/repo.git
```

This clones the repository, but only the last 10 commits are in history. That way if your history really is enormous, you'd save space (again, look twice if space taken by history really is a problem).

Create a work branch as you normally would, work in that branch, merge to `main`, push to `remote`:

```
$ git checkout -b super_feature   # use good branch names, not "dev"
... work, commit, work, commit, work, commit, ... time to merge.
$ git checkout main
$ git merge super_feature         # I usually add --no-ff
$ git push origin main
```

And there you go. You worked on your local **shallow** clone of your `remote`, with limited history.

After a while, your shallow clone will have more and more history. If history space becomes an issue again (but... you know), just ditch the shallow clone and make a new fresh one from the `remote`.

Answer (score -3):

git doesn't care where a repository lives.

You can create a repository on one hard drive, clone it to another hard drive, and push/pull branches between both repositories.

Comment: Can you explain how to do this? I am a total newbie to source control.

Comment: I understand how git works. I understand merging, pushing and pulling, and the different branches you can be working with. My question is specific to the extent that I could not find any tutorials online.

Comment: Rude and unhelpful. While typing some git commands is actually trivial, understanding their implications might be helpful anyway and most tutorials don't cover those in detail.